# Some doubts related to the clear property on the footer in an HTML\CSS template

Tags: html, css, xhtml, css-float

I have implement the following fixed tabless layout using HTML+CSS: http://onofri.org/example/WebTemplate/

(I have to finalize some settings)

This layout have two floatted columns **#content** and **#sidebar** and under these columns there is placed the footer div **#footcontainer**

Ok, so I have to **clear** the elements that I would to place under the tow columns (bring back the elements in the normal flow of the document), to do this I use the **clear** CSS property.

I have read that I could do that in some differents way.

In my example I have created an empty div having id **clearer2** that have the following CSS settings:

```
#clearer2{
    clear: both;
}
```

This work well, but I know that I could also clear directly the footercontainer, in this way:

```
#footcontainer {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 200px;
    background: #4f4f4f url(../images/bgfooter.jpg) repeat-x 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0 -13px 25px 5px #b2b2b2;
}
```

At logic level should be the same thing because I set the **clear: both;** property on an item and then this property is valid for all the successive items. But reading online it seems to me that the first solution is better then the second one. Why is better to creat a new item (as an empty div) that clear then do it directly on the appropriate element (in the example the div **#footercontainer**)

The solution that I have use is a valid solution?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Please include the HTML as well, because your sample page will be gone. Then nobody can reconstruct the whole question.

Answer (score 0):

From the sample page, you have two versions.

HTML with empty clearer `div`

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">...</div>
    <div id="sidebar">...</div>
    <div class="clearer"></div>
</div>
<div id="footcontainer">
    <div id="footer">...</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content, #sidebar { float: left; }
.clearer {
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

and without an empty `div`

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">...</div>
    <div id="sidebar">...</div>
</div>
<div id="footcontainer" class="clearer">
    <div id="footer">...</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content, #sidebar { float: left; }
.clearer { clear: both; }
```

Both approaches are valid and the visual result is the same.

But in the first example, the `container` has a non-zero height, because of the empty clearer div. Because the floating divs are removed from the normal flow, the `container` in the second example has no content and a zero height.

Comment: What do you exactly mean when you say me: that the first example (the one that use the #clearer2 div) has non-zero height (the div is empty so its heig is zero, or not?)
Tnx

Comment: In the first example, there's the empty clearer `div` in the container. So, the first container is *not* empty and has a non-zero height.